# Node.js: Killing sub processes of ChildProcess#spawn

Tags: node.js, process, child-process, spawn

Consider the following code:

```
import {spawn, exec} from 'child_process';

var child = spawn('su',
    [process.env.USER, '-c', 'while (true); do sleep 0.3; echo "tick"; done'], 
    {stdio: ['ignore', 'pipe', 'pipe']}
);

child.stdout.pipe(process.stdout);
child.stderr.pipe(process.stderr);

setTimeout(() => {
    child.kill();
}, 1000);
```

Here I'm trying to run a particular script which runs some other child process (in that example `su` will spawn a `bash` process) and closes it all. However, I can't make it work as I expect.

Calling `child.kill()` kills just the parent process of `su` and not its child `bash`.

What can be done to make it work — calling `` exec(`pkill -TERM -P ${child.pid}`) `` instead of `child.kill()`? As far as I understand, this will kill the whole process tree with parent `child.pid`.

Yet, it has some oddity when combining two methods:

```
setTimeout(() => {
    child.kill();
    exec(`pkill -TERM -P ${child.pid}`);
}, 1000);`
```

This code continues writing `tick` into the console even after the process has been killed.

Why is this happening? Can somebody explain, please?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I was facing the exact problem. I found the solution from [How to kill child processes that spawn their own child processes in Node.js](http://azimi.me/2014/12/31/kill-child_process-node-js.html).

Here is the working form of your code:

```js
const {spawn, exec} = require('child_process');

var child = spawn('./test.sh',
    [], 
    {stdio: ['ignore', 'pipe', 'pipe'], detached: true} // <---- this
);

child.stdout.pipe(process.stdout);
child.stderr.pipe(process.stderr);

setTimeout(() => {
    process.kill(-child.pid); // <---- and this
    // child.kill();
}, 1000);
```

When I ran your original code, the terminal prevented me to run `su` from script, so I modified the testing code to `./test.sh`, which does the same thing:

```sh
(while (true); do sleep 0.3; echo "tick"; done)
```

So the lines that do the magic are `detached:true` and `process.kill(-child.pid)`.

Quoted from the [original site](http://azimi.me/2014/12/31/kill-child_process-node-js.html):

> We can start child processes with {detached: true} option so those processes will not be attached to main process but they will go to a new group of processes. Then using process.kill(-pid) method on main process we can kill all processes that are in the same group of a child process with the same pid group.